# No Framework >> .htaccess >> RewriteRule gives 404 Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I am stuck at something that might seem nothing less but stupid - stuck with a .htaccess RewriteRule.

The Problem:

I am trying to redirect all traffic that comes to the "project" webistes' "non-existant" pages to the index.php as a parameter "q". For example, lets say a user has come to the following URL:

```
http://localhost/project/products/
```

Now obviously there is no directory or file called products, hence,

For the above HTTP request, I want to translate this as:

```
http://localhost/project/public/index.php?q=products
```

The Setup:

Server - Apache 5.3.x with XAMPP
Directory Structure : htdocs/project/public/index.php

What I have already done in an attempt to solve the problem:

Placed a .htaccess file in project directory >> `http://localhost/project/` >> in an attempt to transfer all the traffic to the public directory. The rule for that looks like this...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

Above thing is working and all users getting redirected to the index.php page.

Placed another .htaccess file in the public directory with the follwing code:

```
<IfModule mode_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond....
RewriteCond....
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Now if a user types the URL at the bar: `http://localhost/project/hi`

I want it to be translated as `http://localhost/project/public/index.php?q=hi`

Instead of that it is giving a 404 Error. Also please consider that the actual request being translated to the Apache should not be reflected in the URL bar as a permanent redirect [301].

Does anybody have a solution ?

Comment: Also, it is not listed above (so not sure if this is reflected in your code) but `RewriteEngine on` needs to be declared above any `Rewrite*` (unless it is explicitly turned on in apache config)

Comment: Thanks Joe...I missed it out there...but I am sure it is "ON" on my development machine...

Comment: Somehow the thing is not working for me....

Answer (score 1):

If that file **index.php** is located at /public/ than you should do

```
<IfModule mode_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond....
RewriteCond....
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/public/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your htaccess isn't on the server root.

Then you must define the base url, and use a full path for your rewrite rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/public/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```